# Disable Light Mode in Widget Extension iOS 14

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

My app is supporting DarkMode only, and I'm doing integrate Widget for iOS 14.

Is there any way to **disable** the LightMode for Widget? (Already add `UIUserInterfaceStyle` in the main app `.plist` but doesn't work for Widget)

- `Stock's Widget` always displaying DarkMode even in Editting mode.

[image: Stock Widget always displaying DarkMode even in Editting Widget]

I tried to use `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme` but when open the Edit Mode of Widget, Light Theme still available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the desired color to the widget’s asset catalog, then set the NSWidgetBackgroundColorName in your widget’s build settings.

Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nswidgetbackgroundcolorname